# Difference between dates that are in a column in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I was trying to get the difference between dates. (Date 2 - Date 1)

Here is the sample code:(SQL FIDDLE)

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e11409285d090b7ac87e91e54f28224b

Loc is the Location, 
Date is basically a timestamp.
The item was in location 1 from 12/01/2019 to 12/03/2019 and Item was in location 2 from 12/03 to 12/05 so on.

[image]

I want the output to be as:

[image]

The Days column is calculated by subtracting 
(Date 2 - Date 1) , (Date 3 - Date 2) (Date 4- Date 3) ... (sysdate -  Date N)

How do I do this in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       (lead(date, 1, trunc(sysdate)) over (order by date) -
        date
       ) as days_in_location
from t;
```

Comment: What is the '1' doing in the lead() function?

Comment: @StackOne . . . The default value is the third argument.  To provide a default, you need to give the second argument which is the offset.